# Why is the right side of the block matrix obtained by performing elimination and pivoting on $AI$ equal to $IA^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

When you perform Gauss-Jordan elimination, you start from a matrix $A$ which you augment with the I matrix to obtain $AI$ and then you proceed by subsquent steps of elimination and permutation and you are finally left with a matrix of the shape $IC$.

How does one prove that $C$ is $A^-1$ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do Gaussian Elimination, what you are actually doing is a series of elementary row operations to the augmented matrix. These row operations can be expressed as a series of elementary matrices acting on the augmented matrix $E_n\ldots E_1(A|I)$.

Let $E=E_n\ldots E_1$. We have that $E(A|I)=(EA|EI)=(I|C).$

Since $EA=I$, then $E$ must be the inverse of $A$. So $E=A^{-1}$.

On the opposite side, you have $C=EI$, which means that $C=A^{-1}$.

Comment: So the proof relies on block-wise matrix multiplication property, thanks